# Search in files 0x1F (Unit Separator) using Linux utilities (e.g. grep)

Tags: linux, file, grep

Can't find Unit Separator in files.

Tried using the command:

`grep -liE "\ x1F" ./xml/file_bad.xml`

[image: XML file]

Tell me how to find the names of all files in the folder that contain 0x1F (Unit Separator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `grep -l "$(printf '\x1f')" *`.  If you're using `bash`, you could do `grep -l $'\x1f' *`.

Note, however, that the standard for `grep` specifies that the input is expected to be a text file.  Although many implementations of `grep` work for non-text input, I suppose that behavior is implementation specific.